# How to add fields to existing parquet and generate new parquet (Scala or python)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have existing parquets (say p1) to read into dataframe, and then write it into new parquet file (say p2) after some transformation;

The process is like:

```
val df1 = spark.read.parquet(s"path_to_p1_1")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

val df2 = spark.read.parquet(s"path_to_p1_2")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")

val q = s"""
select 
       cast(ADDRESS as String) as ADDRESS,
       cast(CITY as String) as CITY,
       cast(STATE as String) as STATE,
.......80 fields.......
FROM 
    ( SELECT * FROM table1
        UNION
    SELECT * FROM table2 ) A
  """

val result = spark.sql(q)
res.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(s"path_to_p2")
```

It comes to the need to derive geo info (long and lat) from three columns (address, city, state) and add it back to the p2, or create a new parquet file p3.

The geo part is like below:

```
import requests

http_str = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
addr = '1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA'
#addr = '181 University Ave, Toronto, ON, CANADA'
response = requests.get(http_str + addr)

resp_json_payload = response.json()
latlong = resp_json_payload['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
lat = latlong.get('lat')
lng = latlong.get('lng')
```

lat and lng is the two derived value I want to add to the existing p2 parquet (prefered) or a new p3 parquet.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have values of lat, long as literal then you can use existing function lit while adding new column on dataframe.

If your dataframe is DF then you can do this by
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
DF.withColumn("lat", lit(lat)).withColumn("longitude",lit(longitude))

Comment: Thank you Ramdev, I will test out later. what do you mean if my dataframe is DF? are you just referring to the name (df1, df2)? can you post it with my original code as an answer and I will check ? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I am on Spark 1.6

Comment: My answer was based on Spark 2.x. DF is any dataframe variable name.

Comment: hmm, I got a chance to really apply your code to spark2, the original dataset contains address, city and state, I need to get latitude and longitude from address, city and state and insert the new latitude and longitude value back to the dataframe.

Comment: are you trying to update specific record only to associate lat, long value for address, city and state? My solution is to add new column to existing data frame.

Comment: I need to update all records, thank you.adding new column to existing data frame is what I prefer